# Solving a limit of an integral

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous function, s.t $\forall x\in [0,1]\ \ f(x)\geq 0$.
Prove $\exists x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $$f(x_0) > 1\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}\int f^n(x) dx = +\infty$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.  Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Continuity gives you the existence of an interval $I=(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ on which $f(x)>f(x_0)-(f(x_0)-1)/2>1$, by taking $\epsilon=(f(x_0)-1)/2$ in the definition of continuous at $x_0$. Then bound the integral $\int f^n(x)$ from below with the integral on $I$, and this with $2\delta (f(x_0)-(f(x_0)-1)/2)^n$.